# Getting data from an array by ['value']

Tags: php, arrays

In my array below what is the best way to pull the data I am wanting `['rowid']`.  I have tried a foreach and things like that but I cannot seem to get it.

**Array:**

```
array(4) { 
    ["b5cfec3e70d0d57ea848d5d8b9f14d61"]=> array(7) { 
        ["rowid"]=> string(32) "b5cfec3e70d0d57ea848d5d8b9f14d61" 
        ["id"]=> string(3) "232" 
        ["qty"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["price"]=> string(2) "15" 
        ["name"]=> string(13) " DVD" 
        ["options"]=> array(4) { 
            ["description"]=> string(43) " retail DVD for personal use only." 
            ["image"]=> string(36) "d31e3bc3e820b7faef50a400f721125a.jpg" 
            ["additional_info"]=> NULL 
            ["attributes"]=> string(29) "a:1:{s:6:"Format";s:3:"PAL";}" 
        } 
        ["subtotal"]=> int(15) 
    } 
    ["eda80a3d5b344bc40f3bc04f65b7a357"]=> array(7) { 
        ["rowid"]=> string(32) "eda80a3d5b344bc40f3bc04f65b7a357" 
        ["id"]=> string(3) "267" 
        ["qty"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["price"]=> string(4) "9.99" 
        ["name"]=> string(3) "DVD" 
        ["options"]=> array(4) { 
            ["description"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["image"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["additional_info"]=> NULL 
            ["attributes"]=> NULL 
        } 
        ["subtotal"]=> float(9.99) 
    } 
    ["total_items"]=> int(2) 
    ["cart_total"]=> float(24.99) 
}
```

Comment: Could you please reformat that so that the nesting structure is easier to see? Post it the way `var_dump()` does it, without filling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your array contains values you don't need to iterate over, create an array containing keys to skip, then you can select the row ID each iteration successfully:

```
<?php

// array keys to skip
$skip = array( 'total_items', 'cart_total' );

foreach($yourarray as $key => $row) {

    if(in_array($key, $skip))
        continue; // skip values we don't need in this array

    echo $row['rowid'] . "\n";

}

// output:
// b5cfec3e70d0d57ea848d5d8b9f14d61
// eda80a3d5b344bc40f3bc04f65b7a357

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_column to select a column:

```
$selected_rowids = array_column($yourarrayname, 'row_id');
```

if you want to have a id => row_id array:

```
$selected_rowids = array_column($yourarrayname, 'row_id', 'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

$value)  {
        if(!in_array($skip_values)) {
            echo $value;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }

?>